# /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/experiment.hs:12:1: error: Could not find module ‘Geometry’ Use -v to see a list of the files searched for

Tags: haskell

I have used the terminal on my mac to start ghci. When I write `ls` to find the files in the current directory, the file I wish to load, `experiment.hs` appears in the current directory, its path being `/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/experiment.hs`. However, when I load ghci and write

`:l /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/experiment.hs`

I receive this error:

```
`Prelude> :l /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/experiment.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             
(/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/experiment.hs, interpreted )

/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/experiment.hs:12:1: error:
Could not find module ‘Geometry’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
|
12 | import Geometry
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/experiment.hs:14:1: error:
Could not find module ‘Shapes’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
 |
14 | import Shapes
 | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.`
```

I have also used `experiment.hs` on a windows computer on WinGHCi, with no problems; that is, the following appears:

```
"ghci>" :l experiment
[1 of 3] Compiling Geometry         ( Geometry.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 3] Compiling Shapes           ( Shapes.hs, interpreted )
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( experiment.hs, interpreted )
Ok, three modules loaded.
```

What is going wrong exactly?

In my file `experiment.hs` I have the following modules at the top of the emacs file:

```
  import Data.List

  import Data.Char

  import qualified Data.Map as Map

  import qualified Data.Set as Set

  import Control.Monad

  import Geometry

  import Shapes`
```

I have two files accessible from the terminal via emacs `/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/Shapes.hs`, and `emacs /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/Geometry.hs`, which contain various functions relevant to my `experiment.hs` file. I note that these files do not appear in the current directory on the terminal.

Comment: You need to load the three files: `:l /path/to/experiment.hs /path/to/Geometry.hs /path/to/Shapes.hs`

Comment: Do I do this just by `:l /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/experiment.hs`, followed by `:l /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/Geometry.hs`, followed by `:l /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/Shapes.hs`?

Comment: well the dependencies need to be resolved, so you need to load a module first if another module depends on that module. But if you load the three files in the same `:l`, then Haskell will determine the dependecies itself, and load it in the right order.

Comment: I don't understand the syntax `:l /path/to/experiment.hs /path/to/Geometry.hs /path/to/Shapes.hs`

Comment: `:l` followed by all the paths to the files you want to compile including files that are dependencies.

Comment: Does that literally amount to `:l /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/experiment.hs /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/Geometry.hs /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/Shapes.hs`

Comment: Yes, probably it does.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks :)